# Twitter Typeahead - Duplicate AJAX Suggestions

Tags: jquery, twitter-typeahead

I was able to use the older version of Twitter Typeahead without a problem, my knowledge of the new one is definitely limited, and I am definitely confused on why there are duplicate entries showing up.

This is my Javascript:

```
// Sources
var sources = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: '/sources/prefetch/',
    remote: '/sources/prefetch/'
});

sources.initialize();

$('#a_sources_list').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'sources',
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: sources.ttAdapter()
})
```

**/sources/prefetch/** returns:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Google"},{"id":"3","name":"Yahoo"}]
```

Here is a screenshot of what is happening:[image: Duplicate Results]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was with both `prefetch` and `remote` being called from the same source.

The issue is detailed here:
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/614

Essentially, **BloodHound** has a default limit. If the number of suggestions are under that limit, it calls the remote URL.

There is an option to create a duplicate detector:
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#options

You can use this to make sure the same item doesn't appear twice.

Here's an example of a dupDetector:
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/606#issuecomment-34667422

```
dupDetector: function(remoteMatch, localMatch) {
    return remoteMatch.id === localMatch.id;
}
```

Comment: If I initialize my Bloodhound instance with local rather than prefetch or remote, will my dupDetector ever be called?

Comment: I'm not sure, I would put a console.log in and find out.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think the issue is that I'm not using remote or prefetch. https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/606#issuecomment-51221195